# Clarification on URI path component?

Tags: uri, rfc, rfc3986

According to [RFC 3986 Section 3 - Syntax Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

> The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
> empty (no characters).

Can someone clarify how the path component can be required if it's able to be empty?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the definition of "required" in this context, but I assumed it to mean something along the lines of "must be non-empty," which obviously conflicts with the spec here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, "required" means merely "always present": the scheme and path
components of an absolute URI are always present.

The scheme component can't be empty because the production
"scheme" requires at least one character.

The path component *can* be empty because the production
"path-empty" (part of "hier-part") consists of zero characters.

Comment: So the *component* is required, but not the *data*?  What a weird distinction.

Answer (score 0):

A common practical example of an empty - more precisely, an *abempty* - path is a URI like `http://stackoverflow.com` where the path is empty. The authority component (in this case it is `stackoverflow.com`) alone isn't enough information to identify a *resource*.

When the authority is empty, the path must begin with a `/` in order to distinguish the path from the authority - `scheme:///` is a valid URI - hence an *abempty* path. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403549/5327476) for further reading.