# What does "abempty" mean in the term "path-abempty" in the context of RFC3986?

Tags: rfc3986

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3

And: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

The origin of "abempty" is mysterious to me, and a quick search didn't turn up any definitions of it.

Answer (score 7):

"abempty", as it states in the comments to the right of its usage in the rfc you reference, means that its value can be either an **ab**solute path or **empty** so (**abempty**).

Answer (score 3):

“Abempty”, meaning ***away from*** empty, describes the path’s relationship to its preceding authority.  Where path-abempty is relevant, the hier-part consists of “//”, authority, and path-abempty.  The authority component may be zero length – scheme:/// is a valid URI.

However, when the authority is zero length and the path is empty, there is no way to distinguish the two components, hence a path-abempty path - it "begins with "/" or is empty" (Section 3.3) depending on the circumstances.

Source: http://w3-org.9356.n7.nabble.com/path-abempty-in-URI-td170118.html (See Fielding's response to Petch.)

**NB** The word “abempty” is not a portmanteau of the words absolute and empty.

Please:

```
URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

The hier-part is not optional in the context of a "generic" URI.

```
hier-part = ("//" authority path-abempty) / path-absolute / path-rootless / path-empty
```

The double slashes, interestingly enough, *are not optional* where path-abempty is relevant.  And, jumping ahead a little, the authority may be zero-length:

```
reg-name = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )
```

Path-abempty is relevant where the hier-part consists of “//”, authority, and path-abempty.  Path-abempty is defined as:

```
path-abempty = *( "/" segment )
```

The RFC states, “When authority is present, the path must either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.”  If the reg-name is zero length, a casual reading of that statement might suggest that the following URI is valid:

```
scheme://
```

It’s not.  The very next sentence states, “When authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash characters (‘//’).”  This means that in parsing our URI that begins with “scheme://” we indicate the possibility of a zero-length authority and a zero-length path - otherwise we could stop right there because the URI would be invalid.

In this case, not the common case by any means, the zero-length authority cannot be discerned from the zero-length path.  Hence, when the authority is zero-length, *WE DO NOT HAVE A CHOICE*, the path MUST begin with a forward slash (more precisely, it must match path-abempty) *and* discern the path from the authority; otherwise, and I will say it again: *the URI would be invalid*.

The word “abempty” doesn’t imply that the path may be absolute or empty.  The word means that the path must distinguish itself from the authority, hence it is abempty i.e., *away from* empty.

**Examples:**

This URI is ambiguous because even if it has a zero-length authority and a zero-length path, there is no way to discern it from an invalid URI that omits the authority and has a path that starts with two forward slashes.

```
scheme://
```

This URI is not ambiguous as it clearly contains a zero-length authority and a path-abempty path.

```
scheme:///
```

Answer (score 0):

Given its definition and context in [RFC 3986, Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3): I'm confident that *abempty* is a portmanteau of *absolute* and *empty*; as opposed to *empty* with a Latin *ab*-prefix.

Possible *path* patterns are defined as:

```
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )                    ; begins with "/" or is empty
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ] ; begins with "/" but not "//"
path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )      ; begins with a non-colon segment
path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )         ; begins with a segment
path-empty    = 0<pchar>                            ; zero characters
```

- *Path-abempty* is essentially an **extended** *path-absolute*, combined with *path-empty*.
- *Path-absolute-or-empty* becomes *path-abempty*.

## Disclaimer

My assertion is based solely on inferential conjectures, as I couldn't find the word's etymology, or who coined it. So if anyone has relevant knowledge, to contradict or corroborate: Please, do share!

Comment: It's not like BNF symbols are expected to really mean anything.

Comment: "Path-absolute-or-empty becomes path-abempty."  What is "///"?  It's not path-absolute.  It's not path-empty.  It is path-abempty.

Comment: Correct. As noted by "extended" in the preceding bullet point. I can bold out that word, and perhaps use _Path-extended-absolute-or-empty_ to make it more explicit. May be a bit more distracting, though.

Comment: I noticed the "extended", which is why I referenced the second bullet.  With regard to the first bullet, I can't see how path-abempty is essentially an extension of path-absolute, as they are not used in the same URI context.  Path-absolute is relevant only when the authority is not present.  "Not present" meaning that it is not part of the URI - not just that it is zero-length.